# Finding Values index position in vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am looking to find the index of the searched value in the array with this code. I am getting an error,which has to do with the constant vector, but I am not sure how to fix it.

```
int linearFind( const vector<int>& vec, int y){
    vector<int>::iterator t=find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), y);
    if (t != vec.end())
        return (t-vec.begin());
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, as `vec` is passed as `const&`, the iterators returned by its `begin` and `end` are `std::vector<int>::const_iterator`s, not `std::vector<int>::iterator`s. Thus, `find` will also return a `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` which cannot be converted to a `std::vector<int>iterator` as that would drop a `const`.

So to solve this, either use

```
std::vector<int>::const_iterator t = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), y);
```

of, if you use C++11 or later, the easier

```
auto t = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), y);
```